# Connect AC neutral to USB ground?

Tags: usb, ac

I have an AC supply that plugs into the wall and outputs 8.4V with three pins (+, -, and ground). I would like to save wires and use a six-wire connector to hook a Serial Bus and the AC supply into the same cable. If I had the four USB lines and the power supply, that would be seven pins, and my connector can only hold six. Can I merge the USB GND line with either the neutral or GND lines of the AC supply? What would the effect be?

Comment: Give us a schematic and more information on this mysterious AC supply. Your wordy description of lines and wires is very confusing. But it is unsafe to hook AC neutral to anything that is supposed to be a safe, isolated, low voltage.

Comment: You can add a schematic using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: You MUST NOT have USB or other low-voltage data lines in the same cable or connector as mains AC!

Comment: Definitely not. In some buildings with bad wiring, or if the user uses a "cheater plug" to plug your thing into an un-grounded socket upside-down, or uses it with an adapter in Europe, you will be connecting the USB ground to the *live* wire.

Comment: I think the OP is saying that the low-voltage **output** of the power supply (presumably isolated) has 3 wires -- in other words, he is **not** talking about the line, neutral and earth on the **input** side. The use of the word "neutral" is inappropriate here. Please clarify.